# Delete Item using RestAPI

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I'm using RestAPI to delete item from list. But I dont want to permanently delete it. I want to send it to Recycle Bin. Is there possible with using RestAPI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use HTTP command **DELETE**, it will delete permanently and below is URI struture:

```
http://<sitecollection>/<site>/_api/web/lists(listid)/items(itemid)
```

If you want to delete item and move it to recycle bin, use HTTP command **POST** and below is URI structure:

```
http://<sitecollection>/<site>/_api/web/lists(listid)/items(itemid)/recycle()
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of delete command, use recycle:

http://sitecollectionURL/_api/web/lists(listname)/items(itemid)/recycle()